# Linuxwacom xsetwacom/xorg.conf

Tags: hardware, virtualization, centos, key-mapping

I have a CentOS 6.2 workstation with linuxwacom 0.21.0 installed. I am trying to map a button on a cintiq tablet to a keyboard key.

I can do it successfully using:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 24HD pad" Button 8 "key f11"
```

However, the tablet is connected to a kvm so it is frequently 'disconnected' and 'reconnected'. This means that the key mapping resets. I have tried setting it in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf` using:

```
Option "Button8" "key f11"
```

(I also tried "Button 8") but then I get this error in `Xorg.0.log`:

```
(WW) Option "Button8" requires an integer value
```

Is it not possible to map tablet buttons to keyboard buttons in the `xorg.conf` settings?

If that's not possible is there an alternative way that I can map the keys every time the tablet is connected?

Comment: I would look to create a UDEV rule that detects the absence/presence of the VM and re-add the hardware.

Comment: I was confused as I didnt see any udev rules in /etc/udev/rules.d. But I just realized that the package installs a rule in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/70-wacom.rules. I will try to add a xsetwacom script to that and see if it works.